# Why does master node in redis cannot connect to port 6379 when running it in docker container?

Tags: docker-compose, redis

When trying to run 3 redis instances as 3 docker containers (1 master node and 2 slave nodes) I get the following error for master node:
2023-11-18 11:12:57 1:M 18 Nov 2023 08:12:57.243 # Warning: Could not create server TCP listening socket 172.28.0.1:6379: bind: Cannot assign requested address
2023-11-18 11:12:57 1:M 18 Nov 2023 08:12:57.243 # Failed listening on port 6379 (tcp), aborting.

Sometimes I get the similar error for second slave node but sometimes it works fine.

My docker-compose file:

```
networks:
  hl-lab3-network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16

services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server_component
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
    
      
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client_component

  redis-master:
    image: redis:7
    container_name: master
    command: bash -c "redis-server ./redis-master.conf --appendonly yes --requirepass password"
    ports: 
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - hl-lab3-network
    volumes:
      - ./:/data
  redis-slave-1:
    image: redis:7
    container_name: slave-1
    command: redis-server ./redis-slave1.conf --replicaof master 6379 --requirepass password
    ports: 
      - 6381:6381
    networks:
      - hl-lab3-network
    volumes:
      - ./redis-slave1.conf:/data/redis-slave1.conf
  redis-slave-2:
    image: redis:7
    container_name: slave-2
    command: redis-server ./redis-slave2.conf --replicaof master 6379 --requirepass password
    ports: 
      - 6382:6382
    networks:
      - hl-lab3-network
    volumes:
      - ./redis-slave2.conf:/data/redis-slave2.conf
```

My config files:

redis-master.conf

```
port 6379
bind 172.28.0.1
requirepass password
replica-read-only yes
```

redis-slave1.conf

```
port 6381
bind 172.28.0.2
masterauth password
replica-read-only yes
slaveof master 6379
```

redis-slave2.conf

```
port 6382
bind 172.28.0.3
masterauth password
replica-read-only yes
slaveof master 6379
```

How can I fix that?

I tried changing the ports and IP addresses several times but it did not help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Docker environment, it's often sufficient to rely on Docker's internal networking. Try to **set 'bind' to '0.0.0.0'** in .conf files, or **remove the 'bind' line** completely.

There is a possibility that when you explicitly specify the ip address in the redis config, the docker does not know about it. And when docker tries to set its ip dynamically, it fails and the container does not start.
If you still don't want to let docker determine the ip address itself, then you can set the ip explicitly.

For example:

```html
  redis-master:
    image: redis:7
    container_name: master
    command: bash -c "redis-server ./redis-master.conf --appendonly yes --requirepass password"
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      hl-lab3-network:
        ipv4_address: 127.28.0.1
    volumes:
      - ./server_component/redis-master.conf:/data/redis-master.conf
```